# Using Django-openid-auth

Tags: python, django, openid

I'm trying to implement openid login with Django and having some trouble. The library I'm trying to use now is [Django-openid-auth](https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth). I haven't found any django+openid libraries that have much documentation. How can I actually go about using this as a login and store the information I need for my app based on the users that come in from openid? How does this store the information shared from the openid provider and does this library already store it?

Answer (score 4):

The OpenID identity verification process most commonly uses the
   following steps:

1. The user enters their OpenID into a field on the consumer'ssite, and hits a login button.
2. The consumer site discovers the user's OpenID provider using
   the Yadis protocol.
3. The consumer site sends the browser a redirect to the OpenID
   provider. This is the authentication request as described in
   the OpenID specification.
4. The OpenID provider's site sends the browser a redirect back to
   the consumer site. This redirect contains the provider's
   response to the authentication request.

   your web app needs to keep track of:
   -the user's identity URL and the list of endpoints discovered for
   that URL
   -State of relationships with servers, i.e. shared secrets
   (associations) with servers and nonces seen on signed messages.
   This information should persist from one session to the next
   and should not be bound to a particular user-agent.

hope this helps:D